# How do i speedup my for loop that generates a jvm for each entry in the list and closes?

Tags: bash

I have a code that reads few entry in run time and writes them to a file. In a for loop, i read the content of the file and for each line, i run my code, this code starts a jvm and closes it after the process is done. I have scheduled the job every 5 minutes but the job takes more than 5 minutes due to the slow jvm calls. I would like to know if there is any way i can execute this in parallel!!

```
for i in `cat test.txt`
do
echo "test"
kafka-run-class kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand ### This is my java process which takes time.
done
```

My test.txt contains 100 entries.

Comment: If you don't need to wait for kafka to finish adding a `&` at the end of the line will start them in the background.

Comment: `kafka-run-class … &` and then a `wait` after the loop?

Comment: (OT: ‘*for each line, i run my code*’ isn’t quite true; it’s for each *word*. To read lines you might want to use `while read -r line ; do … ; done < test.txt`.)

Comment: I tried this but, i dont have a definite time when the kafka command finishes so couldn't put a wait. For few lines/words it finished in less than  1sec and for few it finishes in 1min. At one point, we had too many kafka commands running which has caused CPU alerts!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way is with **GNU Parallel**. So, if your file `test.txt` looks like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

You can do:

```
parallel -k echo < test.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

The `-k` just keeps the output in order.

You can also use `--dry-run` to see what it would do without actually doing anything.

You can also use say `-j 12` if you want to run 12 jobs at a time, since, as I have written it, it will just run one job per CPU core in parallel.

**TL;DR;**

I am suggesting you try something like:

```
parallel kafka-run-class kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand < test.txt
```

Comment: This seems to be a good idea but unfortunately, but this isn't tested for RHEL. https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: I guess you can try something with `xargs -P` if that is an issue for you.

Comment: @user3629042 How would you like it tested for RHEL?

Comment: xargs -P -n is doing the trick. But i will need to find the right values so that i dont exhaust the system resources/limits.